# flotar los elementos a la derecha en orden correcto css

Tags: html, html5, css, css3

Tengo cuatro elementos de un menú el primero a la izquierda los otros tres a la derecha, pero al flotar `ul li` `float:right;` los elementos se posicionan de manera desordenada.

```
[Menu3] [Menu2] [Menu1]
```

Pero los elementos deberían mostrarse en este orden:

```
[Menu1] [Menu2] [Menu3]
```

El código completo en ejecución: https://jsfiddle.net/u1eu2dku/

¿Cómo muestro los elementos en orden, pero en el mismo diseño del menú?

```css
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.menu ul li {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
}

.menu ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
   <div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li style="float:left;">logo</li>
    <li><a href="">Menu1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu3</a></li>
  </ul>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución de Shaz me parece perfecta pero por si por alguna razón necesitas compatibilidad con navegadores que no soporten flexbox también pudes usar `display:inline-block` y alinear a la derecha con `text-align`:

```css
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  text-align:right;
}

.menu ul li {
  display:inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
}

.menu ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li style="float:left;">logo</li>
    <li><a href="">Menu1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu3</a></li>
  </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: +1 por aportar una solución que pueden necesitar otras personas al tener este inconveniente.

Answer (score 6):

Una opción es hacerlo con flexbox, justificando los elementos al final de la fila y permitiendo al primero de estos "crecer" para que ocupe el resto del espacio a la izquierda:

```css
.menu {
  width: 100%;
}

.menu ul {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  display: flex;
}

.menu ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
}

.menu ul li:first-child {
  flex: 1;
}


.menu ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>logo</li>
    <li><a href="">Menu1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu3</a></li>
  </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: Tomare muy en cuenta su respuesta a futuro, pero existen problemas de compatibilidad con navegadores que no soporten flexbox. Esto seria otro dolor de cabeza buscar documentación para darle compatibilidad con el resto de navegadores. Pero te agradezco el tiempo que haz tomado en responder, gracias.

Comment: Bueno, eso es cierto y estamos totalmente de acuerdo, la verdad en todos los proyectos que trabajo ahora utilizan flexbox, es soportado a partir de IE10. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox